# How would you add baseboard trim to an angled wall?

Tags: finishing, trim

We have a set of stairs that lead to our basement.  I've made the space underneath in to a small closet. It's been enclosed with drywall.   The floor is a continuation of tile from the laundry room.  I am in the process of adding baseboard trim but the back wall is angled.

Here's a side view:
[image: Closet Side View]

I'm not sure what to do about the area circled in red, because it it angled right down to the floor. How would that area be trimmed out?

One possibility I am considering is running the trim board vertical like this:

[image: Trim Possibility]

But I am unsure if this would work.

**Update**

Both answers below are good.  I am going to use a combination of both and build a small backstop (create some dead space) and then run the trim vertically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd get a 2 x 4, trim it to fit the length and height of your trim piece and screw it in.  [image]

The horizontal lines are the piece of trim that will run along the outside of the staircase.

Answer (score 4):

I'd frame the entire wall vertically where you have less than 1' of height. You'll be unlikely to get much out of that space anyway, considering you need to get from the door past everything else in the closet that should be stacked up to get to the back of the closet. In practice, I rarely see a sloped ceiling go below 3'. Then you just trim that section of the wall normally.

Comment: I agree, framing some dead space would have been optimal, but I am already past the point of framing.  I think this is a good point and answer however and in hindsight I wish I had done that.

Comment: You can frame over what you have done already, and it will be fine. You aren't too late.  You will regret having a weird little space that small objects will roll back into, and that you can't ever clean except with the shop vac crevice tool.